# Vertically center the text in the group headers for an AgGrid control using CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, ag-grid

I'm using react and trying to get the group labels to the left in this screenshot vertically centered, same as the values.

[image: AG GRID screenshot]

I've tried the following with no result:

```css
.ag-header-group-cell-label {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Please add your HTML (as rendered) and the rest of the  relevant CSS (if any) to allow the best answers.  Are you open to use CSS `display: grid` as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is in the right direction. But if you inspect the element, you can see that the container that contains the arrow and the cell text has a class name called `ag-cell-wrapper`, so you need to target that element instead:

```css
/* increase CSS specificity to override the ag-grid styles */
.ag-cell-wrapper.ag-cell-wrapper.ag-cell-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you NearHuscarl.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add margin auto to labels that you want to vertically center ?

```
margin: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of the following:

- `line-height` set to the height of the cells (if that's predictable)
- `vertical-align: middle`

Without more code, that's as much as I can suggest.